# $.css() is not working in android 2.3 but working in android 4.0 + browsers

Tags: android, jquery, css, cordova

Hi I am developing an Android application using Phonegap framework. In that I am setting an image using  "content" in css. below is my code.

HTML:

```
<img id="templateImg" class="templateImg" />
```

CSS:

```
.templateImg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 92%;
    content:url('../images/CLASSY_Car_Main.png');
}
```

Js:

```
imgSrc = $("#templateImg").css('content');
```

it is returning

`imgSrc = url('../images/CLASSY_Car_Main.png')`  in Android 4.0 + but it returning

`imgSrc=' '` in Android 2.3.

How can I get css content in runtime for android 2.3?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: $("#templateImg").css('content') is retuning not retuning url('../images/CLASSY_Car_Main.png') when i use it in android 2.3 version mobile

Comment: Yes, but that's a statement. Do you want to know why that happens? How to work around it? Both?